# Checking on unique email in Psql database

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm building a website with a login system and I want to check if the given email isn't already in my database. But I can't get this to work and there isn't much information that describes my problem.

```
// Unique email
$query = 'SELECT COUNT(email) FROM users WHERE email = :email';
$stmt = $db_conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $userEmail, PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);
$stmt->execute;
print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
$result = $stmt->fetchColumn();
echo $result;
```

The result doesn't echo but I don't understand why not.

Comment: Not really an answer, but this way of checking uniqueness is not the best. 
It would be advisable to create unique index on the email column, then just check for possible error when inserting new row

Answer (score 1):

You havn't got errors or result because statement is not executed.
if you look at the logs you will see an warning for your $stmt->execute (Undefined property: PDOStatement::$execute)
You just only forget parenthesis

so replace

```
$stmt->execute;
```

by

```
$stmt->execute();
```

and you will get your result.

But i'm agree with comment of matiit use unique index if you can